# vlcj stereo mode change

Tags: java, vlcj

I am building a media player app in java using vlcj and now I am facing difficulties in some basic manipulation of audio output. More precisely, VLC has a feature called stereo mode:

Menu bar > Audio > Stereo mode > [Mono, Stereo, Left, Right, etc]

I would like to **access it via vlcj api**, but it seems, the api does not support this feature. At least I have not found any useful api calls so far.

I expect mainly stereo media and I would like to:

- change the actual audio ouput at runtime to mono, or
- mute the left channel (playing only the right channel), or
- mute the right channel (playing only the left channel),
- switch back to stereo (if available ofc)

The question is: Am I missing something and there **is** a hidden api call in vlcj to access this functionality, or is there any other way to mimic this behaviour? Accessing and manipulating audio channels. Preferably at runtime. Has anybody played around with these features?

Answer (score 0):

The vlcj MediaPlayer class has the setAudioOutputChannel method for this, for example:

```
mediaPlayer.setAudioChannel(libvlc_audio_output_channel_t.libvlc_AudioChannel_Stereo);
mediaPlayer.setAudioChannel(libvlc_audio_output_channel_t.libvlc_AudioChannel_Left);
```

...and so on